# Why Boost.Asio SSL request returns 405 Not Allowed?

Tags: c++, ssl, boost, boost-asio

I am trying to send HTTPS request to a server and receive the page contents by only using Boost.Asio(not Network.Ts or Beast or others) by [these code](https://godbolt.org/z/xzohPx8dj) :

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    using namespace boost::asio;

    // what we need
    io_service svc;
    ssl::context ctx(ssl::context::method::tlsv1);
    ssl::stream<ip::tcp::socket> ssock(svc, ctx);

    ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(boost::asio::ip::make_address("157.90.94.153",ec),443);

    ssock.lowest_layer().connect(endpoint); 

    ssock.handshake(ssl::stream_base::handshake_type::client);

    // send request
    std::string request("GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n");
    boost::asio::write(ssock, buffer(request));

    // read response
    std::string response;

    do {
        char buf[1024];
        size_t bytes_transferred = ssock.read_some(buffer(buf), ec);
        if (!ec) response.append(buf, buf + bytes_transferred);
    } while (!ec);

    // print and exit
    std::cout << "Response received: '" << response << "'\n";
}
```

But I keep getting **405 Not Allowed** on my local PC and **400 Bad Request** on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/07913b3c2f0f6735).

What did I do wrong?

Comment: It might be the tls version try
ssl::context ctx(ssl::context::method::tlsv13_client);

Comment: @pabolo12: If it would be a TLS problem there would be no HTTP response in the first place, i.e. neither 405 nor 400. The problem is in the HTTP part, not the TLS part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> ... "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n"
> ```

This is not a valid HTTP/1.1 request. It must at least also contain a `Host` field and the value of the field must match the servers expectation, i.e.

```
   "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: example.com\r\n\r\n"
```

In general, HTTP might look easy but is actually complex and has several pitfalls. If you really need to do HTTP by your own please study the standard.

Comment: The answer is correct, But do you know why it take so long to get the result of the request, comparing to a web browser?

Comment: @malloc: Again, this is about understanding HTTP. In short: don't expect the server to close the connection immediately after sending the response since HTTP/1.1 by default has HTTP keep-alive enabled, i.e. it is waiting for more requests on the same TCP connection. Instead of waiting for a connection close read only as much response data as specified in the HTTP header. See the HTTP standard for more on this.